# How to create model with .g file in flutter-redux-starter

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart, plugins, flutter-redux

./starter.sh make

This command generates not generate .g file. which contain serializer and deserialize.

More about flutter-redux-starter

https://github.com/hillelcoren/flutter-redux-starter

Comment: I resolve this issue by adding flutter bin path in $PATH variable in my mac.